# Huggingface transformer sequence classification inference bug - no attribute 'prepare_inputs_for_generation'

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, transformer-model

I'm trying to run just basic inference with huggingface bert transformer model based on pytorch. Yet it seems that I'm not calling the inference in the right way. Now I can load the model and the tokenizer nicely, but the inference line gives me error. Note that in the code below, I implemented two ways to do infer, both found from online, yet both gave me the same error. So what am I missing?

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, pipeline

model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"
text = "I just had a really nice dinner"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt")

id2label = {0: "POSITIVE", 1: "NEGATIVE"}
label2id = {"POSITIVE": 0, "NEGATIVE": 1}
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    "distilbert-base-uncased",
    num_labels=2,
    id2label=id2label,
    label2id=label2id
)

inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, padding=True)
outputs = model.forward(**inputs)

classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
outputs = classifier(text)

predicted_label_index = outputs.logits.argmax(-1).item()
predicted_label = id2label[predicted_label_index]
print(f"The predicted label for the text is: {predicted_label}")
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\transformers-v4.25-release\inference\infer_classifier_bert.py", line 18, in <module>
    outputs = model.forward(**inputs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\transformers-v4.25-release\src\transformers\models\distilbert\modeling_distilbert.py", line 775, in forward
    logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)  # (bs, num_labels)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\transformers-v4.25-release\src\transformers\generation\utils.py", line 2446, in classifier
    model_inputs = self.prepare_inputs_for_generation(input_ids, **model_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1614, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
AttributeError: 'DistilBertForSequenceClassification' object has no attribute 'prepare_inputs_for_generation'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I looked up the solutions online yet no one had the same error.

Comment: What is the transformers library version? Output of `! pip freeze | grep transformers`

Answer (score 0):

First, try to upgrade your transformer version

```
pip install -U transformers>=4.27.1
```

### How to use the model's forward function for inference?

```
import torch

from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification, pipeline

model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

id2label = {0: "POSITIVE", 1: "NEGATIVE"}
label2id = {"POSITIVE": 0, "NEGATIVE": 1}
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    model_name,
    num_labels=2,
    id2label=id2label,
    label2id=label2id
)

text = "I just had a really nice dinner"

inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, padding=True)

with torch.no_grad():
  outputs = model.forward(**inputs)

print(outputs)
```

[out]:

```
SequenceClassifierOutput(loss=None, logits=tensor([[-0.0663, -0.1213]]), hidden_states=None, attentions=None)
```

##### Converting the `SequenceClassifierOutput` to a dict

```
id2label = {0: "POSITIVE", 1: "NEGATIVE"}

with torch.no_grad():
  outputs = model.forward(**inputs)

  output_labels = [{'label': id2label[int(label)], 'score':float(max(score))} for label, score 
in zip(torch.argmax(outputs.logits, 1),  torch.softmax(outputs.logits, 1))]

  print(output_labels)
```

[out]:

```
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.5391089916229248}]
```

### How to use the pipeline for inference?

```
from transformers import pipeline

model_name = "distilbert-base-uncased"

classifier = pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer)
outputs = classifier(text)

print(outputs)
```

[out]:

```
[{'label': 'POSITIVE', 'score': 0.5137302875518799}]
```

Comment: Thank you. Upgrading to 4.27 immediately solved my problem. I was using 4.25.